# How to print lists of lists of uneven length in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a list shown below. I want to print it as it looks in my shiny application. I tried print(unlist(ls)) where ls is the list shown below but it just printed numbers. I also tried print.char.list from the Hmisc package but it gave error saying

```
Error in x[[1]][1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions.
```

So how can I print the names too? Thanks in advance.

```
$money
bankaccount       cryin   desperate      feelin      likely      loaded      poppin       build      moment 
       0.73        0.73        0.73        0.73        0.73        0.73        0.73        0.62        0.59 
      spend       spent 
       0.51        0.51 

$matter
becauseit    racest   spanish     found    whites     races 
     0.63      0.63      0.63      0.56      0.56      0.55 

$little
appropriate    carrying       usual 
       0.56        0.56        0.56 

$still
    cloth     codes glamorous     grade 
     0.57      0.57      0.57      0.57
```

Comment: What's wrong with `print(ls)`

Comment: I want to render the contents of list as textoutput so print(ls) does not work. I tried output$text <- renderText({  print(ls) }) but did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(shiny)
mylist <- list(letters[1:4], letters[1:5], letters[1:2], letters[1:6])

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$console <- renderPrint({
    print(mylist)
  })

}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("console"))
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

At first i have created example of list of lists (as you have not provided the data in a proper format that is easy to read directly into R, **please consider posting data next time correctly**) and then easily printed it as an console output with `renderPrint()`.