# How can I render a list in a shiny application

Tags: list, shiny, render

I've tried the method of showing lists in a shiny app in the following link:
[How to print lists of lists of uneven length in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744989/how-to-print-lists-of-lists-of-uneven-length-in-shiny) and nothing is displayed so far.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
      verbatimTextOutput("res")
    )
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$res<-renderPrint({
        x=list(nam=('d','h','k','m'),num=(3,2,8,9))
        a=tapply(x[,1],x[,2],summary)

      })}
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: As the output is a list it cannot be rendered in a table(to render table you either need a `vector` or `dataframe`), try `textOutput` and `renderText` instead.

Comment: I would try [listviewer](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/listviewer#shiny-example).

Comment: I've tried rendering it as a text and it gets me this error: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Comment: I've updated my question into a closer code to what I want in fact the link added contains a working code however it did not with my case. Can anyone be of my help?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the syntax of your code inside `list()`. Can you edit your question so that that part works?